# Why am I not able to press the buttons when I come into the page?

Tags: java, android, button, gridview

```
public class Uploads extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView btnAllShops, btnFavourites, btnUploads, btnSettings, btnBuys,
            btnTakePhoto;

    GridView gvUploads;

    PhotoDbAdapter ourHelper;

    private String description, category, price, imagepath;

    final static int cameraData = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploads);
        findViewById();
        onBackPressed();
        sdcard();

    }

    private void findViewById() {
        gvUploads = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvUploads);
        btnAllShops = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnAllShops);
        btnFavourites = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnFavourites);
        btnUploads = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnUploads);
        btnSettings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
        btnBuys = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBuys);
        btnTakePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto);

        btnAllShops.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFavourites.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnUploads.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSettings.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnBuys.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            Intent goMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditUploads.class);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs);
            goMain.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
            startActivity(goMain);
        }
    }

    private void sdcard() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploads);

        // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        cursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, // Which
                                                                                // columns
                                                                                // to
                                                                                // return
                null, // Return all rows
                null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
        // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
        columnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

        GridView gvuploads = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvUploads);
        gvuploads.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
            context = localContext;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView picturesView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                picturesView = new ImageView(context);
                // Move cursor to current position
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                // Get the current value for the requested column
                int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
                picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                                + imageID));
                picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                picturesView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                picturesView
                        .setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(266, 266));
            } else {
                picturesView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            return picturesView;
        }
    }

    private Cursor cursor;

    // Column index for the Thumbnails Image IDs.

    private int columnIndex;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAllShops:
            Intent iA = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllShops.class);
            startActivity(iA);
            break;

        case R.id.btnFavourites:
            Intent iF = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Favourites.class);
            startActivity(iF);

            break;

        case R.id.btnUploads:
            Intent iU = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uploads.class);
            startActivity(iU);

            break;

        case R.id.btnSettings:
            Intent iS = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(iS);

            break;

        case R.id.btnBuys:
            Intent iBuy = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Buys.class);
            startActivity(iBuy);

            break;

        case R.id.btnTakePhoto:
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

before i added the grid-view layout i was able to use the button functions. However, after i inserted the grid-view layout, all i can do is just scroll through the images on the grid-view. What do i do so that i can both scroll through the images and also use the buttons? Thanks

public class Mobile extends Activity {

```
PhotoDbAdapter ourHelper;
ImageView grid_item_image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.mobile);

    grid_item_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    PhotoDbAdapter getImage = new PhotoDbAdapter(this);
    getImage.open();
    String getImagepathe = getImage.getImagePath();

    Toast.makeText(this, getImagepathe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(getImagepathe, null, null);

    grid_item_image.setImageResource(id);

    Intent mobile = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Uploads.class);

    startActivity(mobile);

}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:src="@drawable/sh_uploads" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/hbtn_camera" />
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvUploads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:numColumns="3"
    tools:listitem="@layout/mobile" >
</GridView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnAllShops"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sbtn_home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnFavourites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sbtn_fave" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnBuys"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sbtn_buys" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnUploads"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sbtn_uploads" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sbtn_settings" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have U included layout in one another or there might be problem of context. Please do post some more code for that.

Comment: this is another class that also has a gridview layout. how do i check if there is a problem of context?

Comment: Debug your code and wonder place where your code stops.

Comment: just tried it but somehow no error is showing

Comment: Post your xml layout that contains grid view and buttons

Comment: just posted up my xml file for this class.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the images are into the grid, maybe this helps:

`gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
       if(v.getId() == btnFavourites.getId()){
          //Something happen
       }
    }
});`

Comment: is it okay if you could further explain how this work and roughly where i am suppose to put this line of code? sorry..i am quite new with these things..Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, Im new using StackOverflow, but you can try this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RmwCXpeA

Comment: when i run the app, when i click on the page it just crashes. i checked the logcat and it says use setonItemclicklistener instead. is it a good idea?

Comment: tried using your way however it still does not work..anyways thanks alot